# Where/How does the files downloaded during HTTP GET request gets saved?

Tags: http, http-get, httpserver, react-fullstack

I was going through the concept of HTTP GET request, and I'm kind of stuck wondering where the images downloaded during HTML code response or JSON files downloaded by JavaScript code while rendering a page gets saved?

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers support a number of ways for web sites to store data on the user's computer — with the user's permission — then retrieve it when necessary. This lets you persist data for long-term storage, save sites or documents for offline use, retain user-specific settings for your site, and more. This article explains the very basics of how these work.
Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).